# How to do Wordpress url rewrite in htacess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am a newbie of Wordpress. I come cross a problem about url rewrite rule now.

I made a search form in "homepage.php" and three fields in this form. If user submit this form, three parameters will be sent to another Wordpress page "Results"(slug: results).

```
<form class="filter-form" action="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Results' ) ); ?>" method="get" role="form">
```

I create a page named "Results" using "results.php" as a custom page template.

These three variables are: 1.degree(string) 2.postcodecity(string) 3.department(number eg: 75)

But these three variables are not always have value. Here are the 5 situations:

1.degree  2.postcodecity 3.department 4.degree & postcodecity 5.degree & department

I have a URL like this now:

www.example.com/results/?degree=college&postcodecity=&department=

I need rewrite this URL to its friendly version:

1.www.example.com/results/college (degree)

2.www.example.com/results/75003 - Paris (postcodecity)

3.www.example.com/results/75 (department)

4.www.example.com/results/college/75003 - Paris (degree & postcodecity)

5.www.example.com/results/college/75 (degree & department)

Note: I want to do this directly in [.htaccess] file.

Is there someone can help me? Very gratefull about that.

Comment: Did you check in Admin panel > Settings > Permalink setings. You have some options there and also custom URL structure with tags. check here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: First, sorry about not replying you in time and thanks for your response. I already configured Permalink like this : http://www.example.com/sample-post/. But since this url is from a form submit. So I am not sure why it didn't be formed to a Permalink format.(you can see the url above).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I gave up the method with changing .htaccess file and refers to use Wordpress method. 
Coding in php is easier to control.

To realize my objective, there are two steps should do:

1.Use wp_redirect (Wordpress function) to generate the pretty URL format as you want.

2.Use add_rewrite_rule (Wordpress function) to add custom rewrite rules in order to tell Wordpress how to interpret your pretty URL.